# Anyway to get document.write to work without deleting whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a script to parse a file, get the menu and submenu names and write out a menu. I want to put the html of this menu onto the page. innerHTML works fine for this, but the problem is that I have an additional script that needs to be executed on the menu to make it work correctly. My script makes the HTML of the menu perfectly, but it doesn't work with the secondary script. My guess is that its because innerHTML executes directly to the DOM. I want instead for the html string I created with the script to actually show up in source.

http://pastebin.com/QK1hzsKF

Script I need to run it in conjunction with

```
    <script src=""></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
        });
    </script>
```

I put the output of my script in another page and it worked perfectly. So I am pretty sure its the innerHTML thats the problem.

Document.write just erases the whole page. Anyway I can just insert the html directly in a div just as document.write would?

And the reason I am doing this instead of just doing something like php include is because as you've noticed, I am trying to make functional non-static menus in a CMS (Confluence).

Thanks

Comment: Why do u need `document.write`, why does `innerHTML` doesn't work for inserting content into DIV?

Comment: Where is the document.write?

Comment: @Cole Its not in here. But I tried it by putting document.write("<div id =\"navigationbar\"><nav id=\"cbp-hrmenu\" class=\"cbp-hrmenu\"><ul>"     +      totalString); instead of txt.innerHTML, which is what its at now. But that just erases the page. I have a feeling document.write wouldn't work for what I am doing either though

Comment: @YuriyGalanter My guess is that since innerHTML executes to the DOM directly, it doesn't work with the cbpHorizontalMenu.init(); script. I am not even sure if document.write would work here. But I am at a loss as to what to try now.

Comment: Oh! Nevermind! Got it to work somehow...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `innerHTML` of something, or to add something to the page you use `insertAdjacentHTML`. Example:

```
body = document.getElementById("body");
body.innerHTML = "foo"; //this is what is inside of "body"
body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "bar");
```

Then, the contents of `body` would be `foobar`

Here is a link for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

**UPDATE**
You can have an effect like `insertAdjacentHTML` if you are only using `beforeend`. You can use `body.innerHTML += "foobar"`